# Safe to keep electrical kit close to Consumer Unit (UK)

Tags: electrical

Currently running cables for my home network and I'm hoping to situate my router, switch, and various IoT kit (like a power monitor) in a large ish cabinet which houses the consumer unit and electricity meter.

I'm needing to fit a multi-way extension up there to power everything (if it works out, will ask an electrician to add fixed sockets in the cabinet to avoid additional cable runs) and wanted to get advice on whether it's safe to do so? Could there be any interference from the CU?

Thanks!

Comment: There are several posts here already about running data and electrical cables next to each other and the minimum spacing requirements. TL;DR: not much separation is needed. It's unlikely that you will have any significant issues if you maintain reasonable separation between the equipment and cabling, even if they're in the same closet.

Comment: It will however depend on the quality of your IoT gear. Junky stuff sold cheap on the internet is often of poor quality and bad designs where they cut corners. One of the first corners they cut is often shielding from EM interference.

Comment: note that there are some shady power monitor products out there that have you running low voltage wiring or CT wiring into the panel and mixing , and that's a big Code no-no.